# Python and Oracle Views

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy, cx-oracle

Can someone give me brief information about how to "connect" to an Oracle view from Python?

I looked around but couldn't anything. I'm new to Oracle DB. I will not use it I will only connect it with Python and get some info. But I have only view to connect to.

At first I thought that I can use view like below, to connect:

```
db = sqlalchemy.create_engine('oracle://USER:PASS@SERVER:1521/VIEW_NAME')
```

Then I used this:

```
cx_Oracle.connect(user='USER', password='PASS',
     dsn=cx_Oracle.makedsn('SERVER',1521,'VIEW_NAME'))
```

Then I realized that a view cannot be used as DB Name, because it is just a "tool" to only view the existing table(s).

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A view in an RDBMS like Oracle is essentially a "virtual" table. When querying it, you query it just like you would a table. So connect to the database/schema containing the view, and select from it as usual. The view doesn't feature in the connection details at all, just in the query.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought exactly like you claimed, but server that I try to connect is not mine, it is someone else's. He claimed that I can connect to view without actually connecting to db, so I tried it. ;)

Comment: I'd prefer to call a view a "stored query" rather than a "virtual table".

Comment: So would I - but in terms of explaining to the OP, given his question, the latter term seemed the better to clarify things to me.